# How can I put this SVG onclick attribute that changes opacity into VS2017

Tags: javascript, html, svg, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 does not support styles being changed by Javascript. I don't know how I can solve this please help.  The following code works regularly on Edge, Chrome, and other browsers, but not when I use VS2017 and run the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
  <svg width='100%' height='100%' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect id='myRect'x='0' y='10' width='10' height='100' fill='red' stroke='none' opacity='0.5' 
    onclick='myRect.style.opacity=1' ondblclick='myRect.style.opacity=0.5'/>
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, I really need help with this for an app I'm developing.

Comment: Why do you think that VS2017 does not support styles being changed by JavaScript? Do you have some link to official source for this info? I do not have VS2017, but I think I know where is an error.

Comment: I do not, but I have tried several times to use many dynamic methods to solve it.  It just never worked.  I checked a javascript file and tried to put in the method I'm using as shown above, but it said I couldn't set styles in the terminal.

Comment: about wich terminal do you speak? Try this code `<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background:red" onclick="this.style.background='green'"></svg>`  After mouse click it should change the color. Does it?

Comment: I tried again with the 'this' identifier as you suggested, and witnessed nothing.